# What is the underlying mechanism behind empty slots in Ethereum?

Tags: blocks, consensus, validators, beacon-chain, slots

Ethereum docs says:

> However, occasionally validators might be offline when called to propose a block, meaning slots can sometimes go empty.

What happens when the randomly chosen validator is offline? Is the slot closed as empty, or is there a mechanism to choose a validator `N` number of times before the slot is considered empty?

Let's say there are 3 total validators(A, B and C), of which A is chosen to be the validator. But, A goes offline. Is the slot marked as empty, or is there an algorithm that chooses the next available validator(let's say B)?

Is there a heartbeat mechanism or a time-out mechanism when a validator is chosen? How does the network know the validator is alive? Let's say A was online when chosen by went offline right after it was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

When a validator selected for block production is offline, the network will not have a block in that slot (the slot is considered to be a missed block, or empty) and it simply progresses to the next slot. I don't think there is a mechanism to choose a validator `N` number of times before the slot is considered empty, but instead, further proposals or attestations are built on the last block available from a former slot.

A randomly chosen validator has 12 seconds of time to propose a block. In this case, the network knows the randomly chose validator is online when that validator successfully proposes a block within the 12 seconds interval.

See:

https://consensys.net/blog/codefi/rewards-and-penalties-on-ethereum-20-phase-0/

https://kb.beaconcha.in/glossary

Answer (score 1):

Each slot is every 12 seconds, and each slot has only 1 assigned block proposer: the lucky validator that creates the block for that slot.

If the block proposer is offline, the slot remains empty: the head of the blockchain should remain the same.

An epoch is 32 slots: 6.4 minutes.  Along with the slot, the epoch is a heartbeat mechanism.  An [optimal validator will publish an attestation at every epoch](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/what-is-the-skip-block-exact-definition-in-ethereum-2-0).  At every epoch, you can estimate which validators are online by seeing which ones have published an attestation.  At every slot, you can estimate if a single validator is online by seeing if it proposes a block.